# Alpine Expression Error: Unexpected token ')'

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I am using Laravel with Livewire, I have used a jetstream modal, but when I click in upgrade.blade.php on upgrade button, then modal is not show. and in the console show many error, I have written in below -

file name: upgrade-modal.php

```
<div>
    <div>
        <x-jet-dialog-modal wire:model="upgrademodal" maxWidth="md">
            <x-slot name="title">
                {{-- header --}}
                <div class="w-full h-12 flex items-center">
                    <h2 class="text-xl font-medium tracking-wider flex items-center space-x-3">
                        <span>Unlock Endless Creativites</span>
                        <img src="{{ asset('studio-asset/svgs/leaf.png') }}" alt="heading image" class="w-8 h-8">
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </x-slot>
        
            <x-slot name="content">
               <div class="w-full space-y-5">
                    {{-- monthly and yearly options --}}
                    <div class="w-full flex items-center">
                        
                    </div>
                    {{-- show the plans --}}
                    <div class="w-full space-y-2">
                        @foreach ($this->plans as $index => $plan )
                            <div wire:click="selectPlan({{ $plan->id }})" class="w-full h-20 @if($plan->id == $this->plan_id)  bg-green-50 @else border   @endif rounded cursor-pointer  p-4 flex">
                                <div class="w-10/12 h-full">
                                    <div class=""><span class="text-md font-bold tracking-widest">{{ $plan->name }}</span > - <span> {{ App\Http\Livewire\UpgradeModal::totalCredit($plan->id) }}</span>  <span class="text-sm text-gray-400">Credits/month</span></div>
                                    <div class="space-x-1"><span>US$</span> <span>{{ $plan->price_monthly }}</span><span>/</span> <span>Month</span></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="w-2/12 h-full flex items-center justify-center">
                                   <div class="w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center">
                                    @if($plan->id == $this->plan_id)
                                        <div class="w-5 h-5 rounded-full p-1 bg-green-400 flex items-center">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 8.922 6.927"><path data-name="Combined Shape" d="M3.261 4.798L7.468.245a.86.86 0 011.2 0 .968.968 0 010 1.3l-4.676 5.06a1 1 0 01-1.468 0L.251 4.147a.968.968 0 010-1.3.86.86 0 011.2 0" fill="#fafafa"></path></svg>
                                        </div>
                                    @else
                                        <div class="w-5 h-5 rounded-full border-2"></div>
                                    @endif
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    {{-- promo code --}}
                    <div class="w-full h-12 flex items-center">
                        <span class="px-5 h-8 flex items-center cursor-pointer bg-yellow-100 rounded ">Have a Promo Code ?</span>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </x-slot>
        
            <x-slot name="footer">
                {{-- payment button --}}
                <div class="w-full h-12 flex items-center justify-end">
                    <span wire:click="payment()" wire:loading.class="text-gray-700" wire:loading.attr="disabled" class="px-5 h-10 text-sm tracking-wider flex items-center cursor-pointer bg-indigo-500 rounded text-white">Get Started with {{ $this->plan_name }}</span>
                </div>
            </x-slot>
        </x-jet-dialog-modal>

        {{-- javascript --}}
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(function() {
    
        /*------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------
        Stripe Payment Code
        --------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------*/
        
        var $form = $(".require-validation");
        
        $('form.require-validation').bind('submit', function(e) {
            var $form = $(".require-validation"),
            inputSelector = ['input[type=email]', 'input[type=password]',
                            'input[type=text]', 'input[type=file]',
                            'textarea'].join(', '),
            $inputs = $form.find('.required').find(inputSelector),
            $errorMessage = $form.find('div.error'),
            valid = true;
            $errorMessage.addClass('hidden');
        
            $('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
            $inputs.each(function(i, el) {
            var $input = $(el);
            if ($input.val() === '') {
                $input.parent().addClass('has-error');
                $errorMessage.removeClass('hidden');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            });
        
            if (!$form.data('cc-on-file')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //   Stripe.setPublishableKey($form.data('stripe-publishable-key'));
            Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_51JEZdbSCJoZTKKTopB08PolKHDBMgGMsTskcj3Hbdjic5XCn9Z1ovtH0sgUMVaPhOse8CAhMsqzvP2MAwqSGOv8f00gGuc0A7H');
            Stripe.createToken({
                number: $('.card-number').val(),
                cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
                exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
                exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
            }, stripeResponseHandler);
            }
        
        });
        
        /*------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------
        Stripe Response Handler
        --------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------*/
        function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
            if (response.error) {
                $('.error')
                    .removeClass('hidden')
                    .find('.alert')
                    .text(response.error.message);
            } else {
                /* token contains id, last4, and card type */
                var token = response['id'];
                    
                $form.find('input[type=text]').empty();
                $form.append("<input wire:model='stripeToken' type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "'/>");
                $form.get(0).submit();
            }
        }
        
    });
    </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

the error show in console:

```
p.js:431 Alpine Expression Error: Unexpected token ')'

Expression: "{ show: window.Livewire.find('RVerQgFNN56RogBnUr0F').entangle('upgrademodal').defer, focusables() { // All focusable element types... let selector = 'a, button, input:not([type=\'hidden\']), textarea, select, details, [tabindex]:not([tabindex=\'-1\'])' return [...$el.querySelectorAll(selector)] // All non-disabled elements... .filter(el => ! el.hasAttribute('disabled')) }, firstFocusable() { return this.focusables()[0] }, lastFocusable() { return this.focusables().slice(-1)[0] }, nextFocusable() { return this.focusables()[this.nextFocusableIndex()] || this.firstFocusable() }, prevFocusable() { return this.focusables()[this.prevFocusableIndex()] || this.lastFocusable() }, nextFocusableIndex() { return (this.focusables().indexOf(document.activeElement) + 1) % (this.focusables().length + 1) }, prevFocusableIndex() { return Math.max(0, this.focusables().indexOf(document.activeElement)) -1 }, }"

p.js:431 Alpine Expression Error: show is not defined

Expression: "show"

p.js:484 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
    at new AsyncFunction (<anonymous>)
    at safeAsyncFunction (app.js:484:14)
    at generateFunctionFromString (app.js:490:14)
    at generateEvaluatorFromString (app.js:495:14)
    at normalEvaluator (app.js:464:19)
    at evaluateLater (app.js:451:10)
    at evaluate (app.js:447:3)
    at app.js:2784:15
    at Function.<anonymous> (app.js:1206:55)
    at flushHandlers (app.js:588:46)


p.js:434 Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined
    at eval (eval at safeAsyncFunction (app.js:484:14), <anonymous>:3:32)
    at app.js:502:21
    at tryCatch (app.js:423:12)
    at app.js:2244:39
    at reactiveEffect (app.js:1659:16)
    at Object.effect2 [as effect] (app.js:1634:5)
    at effect (app.js:62:33)
    at wrappedEffect (app.js:78:27)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (app.js:2244:25)
    at eval (eval at safeAsyncFunction (app.js:484:14), <anonymous>:3:32)
eval @ VM40496:3
(anonymous) @ app.js:502
tryCatch @ app.js:423
(anonymous) @ app.js:2244
reactiveEffect @ app.js:1659
effect2 @ app.js:1634
effect @ app.js:62
wrappedEffect @ app.js:78
(anonymous) @ app.js:2244
eval @ VM40495:3
(anonymous) @ app.js:502
tryCatch @ app.js:423
evaluate @ app.js:447
(anonymous) @ app.js:2718
(anonymous) @ app.js:1206
flushHandlers @ app.js:588
stopDeferring @ app.js:593
deferHandlingDirectives @ app.js:596
initTree @ app.js:791
(anonymous) @ app.js:746
start @ app.js:745
./resources/js/app.js @ app.js:5169
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:22659
(anonymous) @ app.js:22824
__webpack_require__.O @ app.js:22696
(anonymous) @ app.js:22826
(anonymous) @ app.js:22828
setTimeout (async)
handleError @ app.js:434
(anonymous) @ app.js:502
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ app.js:502
tryCatch @ app.js:423
(anonymous) @ app.js:2244
reactiveEffect @ app.js:1659
effect2 @ app.js:1634
effect @ app.js:62
wrappedEffect @ app.js:78
(anonymous) @ app.js:2244
eval @ VM40495:3
(anonymous) @ app.js:502
tryCatch @ app.js:423
evaluate @ app.js:447
(anonymous) @ app.js:2718
(anonymous) @ app.js:1206
flushHandlers @ app.js:588
stopDeferring @ app.js:593
deferHandlingDirectives @ app.js:596
initTree @ app.js:791
(anonymous) @ app.js:746
start @ app.js:745
./resources/js/app.js @ app.js:5169
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:22659
(anonymous) @ app.js:22824
__webpack_require__.O @ app.js:22696
(anonymous) @ app.js:22826
(anonymous) @ app.js:22828
3app.js:434 Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined
    at eval (eval at safeAsyncFunction (app.js:484:14), <anonymous>:3:32)
    at app.js:502:21
    at tryCatch (app.js:423:12)
    at app.js:2835:17
    at reactiveEffect (app.js:1659:16)
    at Object.effect2 [as effect] (app.js:1634:5)
    at effect (app.js:62:33)
    at wrappedEffect (app.js:78:27)
    at Function.<anonymous> (app.js:2835:3)
    at flushHandlers (app.js:588:46)
```

I expect to sovle the error and when click , then modal show.